# Flutter: Platform Exception upon cancelling Google Sign In flow

Tags: firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter, google-signin

This is my pubspec.yaml. I'm using Flutter:

```
  dependencies:
    flutter:
      sdk: flutter

    cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
    http: ^0.11.3

    #Google Sign In
    google_sign_in: 3.0.3
    firebase_auth: ^0.5.18
    flutter_svg: ^0.5.0
```

I can authenticate fine, the Sign In structure works, however if I'm at the Google Sign In and I cancel Google's authentication flow by hitting the back button on my physical device (S7 Edge), the application locks up and returns this:

```
Exception has occurred.
PlatformException(sign_in_failed, Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}, null)
```

Here is the log of the situation. It seems to me as if it fails silently:

```
I/InputMethodManager(13050): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/ViewRootImpl@3c3c6cd[SignInHubActivity](13050): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D/ViewRootImpl@3c3c6cd[SignInHubActivity](13050): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
V/InputMethodManager(13050): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@4d4a683 nm : com.xYNP82hMsgxfvzA.pqfrontend ic=null
I/InputMethodManager(13050): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
D/ViewRootImpl@3c3c6cd[SignInHubActivity](13050): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
D/ViewRootImpl@a981422[MainActivity](13050): MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
    V/InputMethodManager(13050): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@5990000 nm : com.xYNP82hMsgxfvzA.pqfrontend ic=null
I/InputMethodManager(13050): startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
I/FlutterActivityDelegate(13050): onResume setting current activity to this
D/OpenGLRenderer(13050): eglDestroySurface = 0x7cb041df50
D/ViewRootImpl@3c3c6cd[SignInHubActivity](13050): Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1440,2560] new=[0,0][1440,2560] result=0x5 surface={valid=false 0} changed=true
D/ViewRootImpl@3c3c6cd[SignInHubActivity](13050): dispatchDetachedFromWindow
D/InputEventReceiver(13050): channel 'a2e7010 com.xYNP82hMsgxfvzA.pqfrontend/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity (client)' ~ Disposing input event receiver.
D/InputEventReceiver(13050): channel 'a2e7010 com.xYNP82hMsgxfvzA.pqfrontend/com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.internal.SignInHubActivity (client)' ~NativeInputEventReceiver.
```

Haven't found any solutions online, can someone help me out?

Update:
I just got an Exception notice in the logs:

```
E/flutter (13050): [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (13050): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, Status{statusCode=ERROR, resolution=null}, null)
E/flutter (13050): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:547:7)
E/flutter (13050): #1      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:279:18)
E/flutter (13050): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13050): #2      GoogleSignIn._callMethod (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:183:58)
E/flutter (13050): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13050): #3      GoogleSignIn._addMethodCall (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:222:20)
E/flutter (13050): #4      GoogleSignIn.signIn (package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart:293:48)
E/flutter (13050): #5      handleSignIn (file:///C:/Users/dark_/picquest-dev/pq_frontend/lib/src/services/auth.dart:9:62)
E/flutter (13050): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13050): #6      main (file:///C:/Users/dark_/picquest-dev/pq_frontend/lib/main.dart:18:10)
E/flutter (13050): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13050): #7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:279:19)
E/flutter (13050): #8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:165:12)
```

It points to my auth service which I wrote: Here's that:

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'dart:async';

final GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignIn() async {
  final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn();
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth = await googleUser.authentication;

  final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.signInWithGoogle(
    accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
  );
  print("signed in " + user.displayName);
  return user;
}


Future<Null> handleSignOut() async {
  await _auth.signOut();
  await _googleSignIn.signOut();
}
```

Here's where that's called:

```
void main()  {
  //Default unauthenticated home page

  try {
    auth.handleSignIn();
  } catch(e) {
    print(e);
  }

  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.portraitUp,
    DeviceOrientation.portraitDown
    ]);

    runApp(new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Test',
      home: _defaultHome,
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primaryColor: Colors.white
      ),
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder> {
        '/onboarding/basic-info': (BuildContext context) => new UserOnBoarding_BasicInfo_Page(),
        //'/onboarding/interests': (BuildContext context) => new UserOnBoarding_Interests_Page(),
        '/avatar-repository': (BuildContext context) => new AvatarRepositoryPage(),
        '/login': (BuildContext context) => new LoginPage(),
        '/app/settings': (BuildContext context) => new AppSettingsPage()
      },
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/futures-error-handling

Comment: That's helpful! I'm still working through how I can catch these errors

Comment: Update: its 2020 and we have a different [issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44431) for this. **no** fix though.

Answer (score 13):

You can capture the error using `catchError` like this:

```
      Future<FirebaseUser> handleSignIn() async {
        final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser =
            await _googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((onError) {
          print("Error $onError");
        });
        if (googleUser != null) {
          final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
              await googleUser.authentication;
          final FirebaseUser user = await _auth
              .signInWithGoogle(
            accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
            idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
          )
              .catchError((onError) {
            print("error $onError");
          });
          if (user != null) {
            print("signed in " + user.displayName);
            return user;
          }
        }

        return null;
      }
```

Comment: Hey Diego, it still hasn't stopped the error from throwing, I'll try more. It doesn't seem as if the errors are being printed

Comment: Could you call auth.handleSignIn inside your first widget and not before runApp?

Answer (score 9):

According to the comments on the `signIn()` function in `google_sign_in.dart`, request cancellation should return `null` instead of throwing a `PlatformException`:

`` /// Returned Future resolves to an instance of [GoogleSignInAccount] for a
  /// successful sign in or `null` in case sign in process was aborted. ``

I've raised an issue for this bug in the Flutter repository [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22113)

For now, you'll have to stick with catching the error manually

Comment: Legend. I hope that bug gets fixed for others down the line. We pivoted from Flutter to Android Java for a number of reasons, one of which was this problem.

Answer (score 9):

This error will not occur in release mode as said by @monojmnj
*I think this is error causing by IDE* Because when you 
**run your app in terminal there is no exception caused.**

Comment: Confirmed. Running in flutter cli throws no errors - "flutter run"

Comment: If we upload to production will this error still be there?

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that this issue still persists as of today **(but only in debug mode)**,And when sign in cancelled in the release mode the app doesnt crash/freeze and continues to function,So I feel this is mostly with the ide that throws the exception and dart is not able to capture it.so till it gets fixed,so a simple workaround is to use the release version of the app.

> **Note**: Make sure to sign the app and enter the hash in firebase console otherwise google signin wont work in release mode

Comment: Yes, This is true. This works for me. Release APK will work fine. I think it's an IDE issue when it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

I have also recently faced this error and, I have found out that the `.catchError()` callback wasn't being called in the debug mode (which is when you click the `Run->Start Debugging` button in VSCode).

However, when you type in flutter run -d , then, the `.catchError()` method gets called back as it is not in debug mode.

To get your preferred simulator's code paste this line of code in the terminal:

```
instruments -s devices
```

If that doesn't work, you can also try pasting this:

```
xcrun simctl list
```

The  `.catchError()` method will get called unlike before and the code inside that will get executed as expected!

Additionally, the app won't crash anymore with a `PlatformException()` and instead you will get a log like this one:

```
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'uid' was called on null.
Receiver: null
```

I have been facing this problem in Google Sign In too, in which the `.catchError()` was not being called!

In conclusion, if you have some error with handling errors in Firebase Authentication, you should first try to first run in through the terminal. Thanks, and I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One workaround on interrupting the Google sign in flow I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59561486/canceling-google-sign-in-cause-an-exception-in-flutter) is to do the following:

Find the package: `package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart` and change:

```
final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = await invokeMethod<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(method, arguments);
    return result?.cast<K, V>();
```

to:

```
try {
    final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = await invokeMethod<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(method, arguments);
    return result?.cast<K, V>();
} on PlatformException catch (err) { // Checks for type PlatformException
    if (err.code == 'sign_in_canceled') { // Checks for sign_in_canceled exception
        print(err.toString());
    } else {
        throw err; // Throws PlatformException again because it wasn't the one we wanted
    }
}
```

Comment: it works but it needs some modification

Answer (score 0):

On my project case

Just run it via terminal, it happens when you run using vscode (f5), but when you run using `flutter run` on the terminal, the exception will not happen.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this issue with my release build as of today. Cancelling Google login in debug mode was working fine. After making a release build and also uploaded to TestFlight the App used to crash when ever I tried this functionality. Even my app got rejected from App store for this. I was not getting this issue with Android build thou. The only thing that fixed this bug was adding a null check. Even with try can catch the IoS App used to crash. Hope this helps someone in the same boat as me as it took 3 days for me figure this out and solve it

```
 try {
  // Trigger the authentication flow
  final GoogleSignInAccount? googleUser = await GoogleSignIn().signIn();
  if(googleUser == null){
    return LoginUserData(functionRespData: FunctionRespData( error: "login-error"));
  }

  // Obtain the auth details from the request
  final GoogleSignInAuthentication? googleAuth =
      await googleUser?.authentication;

  // Create a new credential
  final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
    accessToken: googleAuth?.accessToken,
    idToken: googleAuth?.idToken,
  );
  // UserCredential? userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser
  //     ?.linkWithCredential(credential);
  // Once signed in, return the UserCredential
  UserCredential userCredential =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(credential);

  return LoginUserData(userData:_userFromFirebase(userCredential.user));
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  return LoginUserData(functionRespData: FunctionRespData(error: e.message));
} catch(e){
  return LoginUserData(functionRespData: FunctionRespData( error: "login-error"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cancel the flow, the call to `final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn()` returns a null value. The rest of the flow is dependent on the value not being null, so return early if that's the case.

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleUser = await _googleSignIn.signIn()
if (googleUser == null) {
  return; // or throw an error
}
```