# Canceling Google Sign In cause an exception in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-signin

I am trying to implement Google Sign In in my android flutter app, but I have this problem:

When user cancel Google sign in (tap on back button) this exception is throw.

> PlatformException (PlatformException(sign_in_canceled, com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException: 12501: , null))

I found that from some newer version this should be fixed and it should return null instead of an exception. Currently I am using **google_sign_in: ^4.1.1**

I tried to wrap my code inside try-catch block or using .catchError() on the method, but nothing help.

My code looks like this:

```
  Future googleSign(BuildContext context) async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
        await googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((onError) => print(onError));

    final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication =
        await googleSignInAccount.authentication;

    final AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
      accessToken: googleSignInAuthentication.accessToken,
      idToken: googleSignInAuthentication.idToken,
    );

    final AuthResult authResult = await _auth.signInWithCredential(credential);

    return authResult.user.uid;
  }
```

Do you have any idea, how to handle this exception?
Thanks.

Comment: why is this method `googleSign` called when user clicks back button?

Comment: Noo, its not... This method is called when user click on Google Sign In button, but when user cancel sign in (by clicking on back button) this exception is throw.

Comment: I have this same issue `PlatformException(FirebaseException, An internal error has occurred. [ 7: ], null) ` But it doesn't affecting the sign in functionality.

Comment: Yes, I have just simply ignore the exception

Answer (score 11):

This issue only resides in debug mode.
If the user cancels the Google Sign In then the app won't freeze or crash in the release mode.
So, **no need to worry** as this won't create any problem in the release mode.

Comment: Still happens in 2023. App froze when going back (without selecting an account to sign in with) in debug mode. Otherwise works fine.

Answer (score 10):

*The issue seems to be caused by an inability of the Dart VM to correctly detect exceptions that are caught with `catchError()` as explained in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56802675/dart-flutter-debugger-stops-on-caught-exceptions)*

There doesn't seem to be a perfect fix to this bug. However, I came across a somewhat good workaround on [Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44431#issuecomment-619482424).

It requires you to edit `package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart`.

You would have to wrap this

```
final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = await invokeMethod<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(method, arguments);
return result?.cast<K, V>();
```

with a `try/catch` block as follows  (found at the beginning of `invokeMapMethod`)

```
try {
    final Map<dynamic, dynamic> result = await invokeMethod<Map<dynamic, dynamic>>(method, arguments);
    return result?.cast<K, V>();
} on PlatformException catch (err) { // Checks for type PlatformException
    if (err.code == 'sign_in_canceled') { // Checks for sign_in_canceled exception
        print(err.toString());
    } else {
        throw err; // Throws PlatformException again because it wasn't the one we wanted
    }
}
```

You might also want to check if `googleSignInAccount` is `null` in which case, you should return `return null` to prevent further exceptions like `NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'authentication' was called on null`

So, your code can be re-written as

...

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = await googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((onError) => print(onError));

// Return null to prevent further exceptions if googleSignInAccount is null
if (googleSignInAccount == null) return null;

final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleSignInAuthentication = await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
```

...

I hope this is easy to follow and it **actually works** for you.

Comment: Hey, how can I find platform_channel? I don't see any package folder in my directory.

Comment: It can be found in your Flutter installation directory.
<Flutter Installation Directory>\packages\flutter\lib\src\services

https://ibb.co/j62dTmm


By the way, I think the issue should have been fixed properly by now.

Comment: could you put a more complete example of how you do that?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to fix the issue.

```
static Future<User?> signInWithGoogle() async {
    final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();

    GoogleSignInAccount? googleSignInAccount;

    try {
      googleSignInAccount =
          await googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((onError) => null);
    } catch (e) {
      // print(e);
    }

    if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
      final GoogleSignInAuthentication googleAuth =
          await googleSignInAccount.authentication;
      final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
        accessToken: googleAuth.accessToken,
        idToken: googleAuth.idToken,
      );

      try {
        final UserCredential authResult =
            await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
        final User? user = authResult.user;

        return user;
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
        if (e.code == 'account-exists-with-different-credential') {
          // ...
        } else if (e.code == 'invalid-credential') {
          // ...
        }
      } catch (e) {
        // ...
      }
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: I added this code and got it working..without the need to change the dart source.

Answer (score 0):

I think u run with debugging mode. So, flutter show every single error, it is ok if u fix or not. So, try to run with without debugging mode and the error will fix, this will not throw the error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you cancel the sign-in flow, `await googleSignIn.signIn()` returns null. The crash occurs because you go ahead to create `AuthCredential` with empty values and then pass that along to `signInWithCredential`.

To fix the problem, make sure to return early if the result of calling `googeSignIn.sign()` is null. E.g:

```
final GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount =
    await googleSignIn.signIn().catchError((onError) => print(onError));

if (googleSignAccount == null) {
  return;
}
```